# Efficiency of Fortran ndarray versus n*1d arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran, hpc

Well this is one I'm struggling with since I started working on the actual code I'm working with right now.
My advisor wrote this for the past ten years and had, at some point, to stock values that we usually store in matrix or tensors.

Actually we look at matrix with six independent composents calculated from the Virial theorem (from Molecular dynamics simulation) and he had the habits to store 6*1D arrays, one for each value, at each recorded step, ie xy(n), xz(n) yz(n)... n being the number of records.

I assume that a single array s(n,3,3) could be more efficient as the values will be stored closer from one another (xy(n) and xz(n) have no reason to be stored side to side in memory) and rise less error concerning corrupted memory or wrong memory access. I tried to discuss it in the lab but eventually no one cares and again, this is just an assumption.

This would not have buggued me if everything in the code wasn't stored like that. Every 3d quantity is stored in 3 different arrays instead of 1 and this feels weird to me as for the performance of the code.

Is their any comparable effect for long calculations and large data size? I decided to post here after resolving an error I had due to wrong memory access with one of these as I find the code more readable and the data more easy to compute (s = s+... instead of six line of xy = xy+... for example).

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Add a version tag for version specific questions.

Comment: This is really difficult to answer and very open without a specific code. It really depends how you access the arrays. It may be faster or it may be slower. It is similar to the choice which index should be the first and which should be the second.

Comment: Lab discussions, SO discussions, discussions in general are no more the appropriate for answering this type of question than they are for resolving questions such as *who is the tallest grad student in the class*.  Take some measurements.

Comment: @Mark: I wasn't a skilled fortran user when i came in the lab and profiling was out of my skills (I'm slowing starting to learn about it). I though the IT engineers working on the code could answer that, yet they didn't seem to bother do the profiling. I needed a first opinion on weither or not it could have some interest. I'll try to do some profiling tests then.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the columns are close to each other is not very important, especially if the leading dimension `n` is large. Your CPU has multiple prefetch streams and can prefetch simultaneously in different arrays of different columns.

If you make some *random* access in an array `A(n,3,3)` where `A` is allocatable, the dimensions are not known at compile time. Therefore, the address of a random element `A(i,j,k)` will be `address_of(A(1,1,1)) + i + (j-1)*n + (k-1)*3*n`, and it will have to be calculated at the execution every time you make a random access to the array. The calculation of the address involves 3 integer multiplications (3 CPU cycles each) and at least 3 adds (1 cycle each). But regular accesses (predictible) can be optimized by the compiler using relative addresses.

If you have different 1-index arrays, the calculation of the address involves only one integer add (1 cycle), so you get a peformance penalty of at least 11 cycles for each access when using a single 3-index array.

Moreover, if you have 9 different arrays, each one of them can be aligned on a cache-line boundary, whereas you would be forced to use padding at the end of lines to ensure this behavior with a single array.

So I would say that in the particular case of `A(n,3,3)`, as the two last indices are small and known at compile time, you can safely do the transformation into 9 different arrays to *potentially* gain some performance.

Note that if you use often the data of the 9 arrays at the same index `i` in a random order, re-organizing the data into `A(3,3,n)` will give you a clear performance increase. If a is in double precision, `A(4,4,n)` could be even better if `A` is aligned on a 64-byte boundary as every `A(1,1,i)` will be located at the 1st position of a cache line.

Comment: My C habits made me fail to notice the "wrong" order of my indices. And concerning the access of my data, for now it is essentially about storing at time _n_ and writing them in order to the output file. Still, I have now a bit of insights with this elements and as I said in comments above, I'll try to profile this if I've got enough time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you always loop along `n` and inside each loop need to access all the components in the matrix, storing the array like `s(6,n)` or `s(3,3,n)` will benefit from [cache optimization](http://docs.cray.com/books/004-2518-002/html-004-2518-002/z830465458dep.html).

```
do i=1,n
   ! do some calculation with s(:,i)
enddo
```

**However**, if your innerloop looks like this

```
resultarray(i)=xx(i)+yy(i)+zz(i)+2*(xy(i)+yz(i)+xz(i))
```

Don't border to change the array layout because you may break the [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) optimization.

Comment: I think this misrepresents the referenced document which offers the usual advice that, since Fortran arrays are stored in *column-major* order, one should iterate across the leftmost index in the inner-most loop of a loop nest.  That document also points out that the Cray compiler (nearly 20 years ago) could, and would, re-order loop nests for cache efficiency when it could determine that it was safe to do so.  That's a reasonable expectation for all (?) current Fortran compilers.

Comment: In case of this question (Molecular dynamics simulation), there is no nested loop. We should talk about memory access patern instead of looping order. In MD simulations, you need all coordinates (matrix components) of a single atom at a 'same' time. This access pattern is implied by the algorithm thus cannot be eaily changed.

Comment: note he says "(xy(n) and xz(n) have no reason to be stored side to side in memory)" . Thats not the case for this example.